# Using variable index in matlab

Tags: matlab

If we have `k=1:n`, and then we put `k` in a function so we get `fk=f(tk)` for some values of `tk`, when I apply the program I get just `fk` for each value of `k`, it is not named by `f1`, `f2`.
Here is the statements

```
for k=1:n
t=linspace(0,0.25)
tk=t.*(k-1)/n
f=inline('x.^0.2')
fk=f(tk)
```

Comment: Please reformat your code viz. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: could you make your purpose more clear?

Comment: This is a site for mathematics, not Matlab coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, it is not a good idea to create new variables in a loop. It is better to have an array or a cell array. However, if you really need it, then one possible solution is:

```
n = 5;
t = linspace(0,0.25);
f = @(x) x.^0.2;
for k = 1:n
    tk = t.*(k-1)/n;
    s = ['f' num2str(k) ' = f(tk);'];
    evalin('caller',s);
end
```

I avoide `inline` because it will be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is very useful. But I didn't touch the use of (evalin)?? what if I want to add another index j and calculate fj-fk? Is it just like this or the names doesn't match the values of the function??

Comment: @HawraaAbbas ```evalin``` just executes a string. So I create the string ```f1=f(tk);```, where 1 in ```f1``` is created based on the current index ```k```.
Please do not forget to mark an answer as a solution if it is.